# How to include a channel name and a username in slack incoming webhook?

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

I am trying to post a message to a channel in slack using an incoming webhook, in the channel option i see you can either pass the username of a channel name,  is there a way to include the @channel in the channel name as well so that it sends an alert to all the user?

Comment: You would put that in the message text, not in the channel name right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that works.

You just need to include a special link in your message text and Slack will automatically alert all users of that channel.

e.g. `<!channel>`

See [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users) for more examples on how to use links in a message.